# Automatic Data Persistence in D

Tags: object, reflection, persistence, d

Have anybody thought about implementing some kind of automatic data (object) persistence in D? My ideal solution to this problem would be something like:

```
@persistent int x = 1;
```

This works most seamelessly for static variables but dynamic ones would also be possible.

These variables would be stored in a key-value store database. Keys could be fingerprinting digests based on the scoped variable name and type plus some digest of the currently loaded code.

Comment: you'll want to post this on the [digital mars forum](http://forum.dlang.org/group/digitalmars.D) and then see what they say, I don't think they'll do this for a number of reasons.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could do something kinda similar with a template. Check this out:

```
import std.stdio;

// do not declare two of these on the same line or they'll get mixed up
struct persistent(Type, string file = __FILE__, size_t line = __LINE__) {
    Type info;
    alias info this;

    // require an initializer
    @disable this();

    // with the initializer
    this(Type t) {
        // if it is in the file, we should load it here
        // else...
        info = t;
    }
    ~this() {
        // you should actually save it to the file
        writeln("Saving ", info, " as key ",
            file,":",line);
    }
}

void main() {
    persistent!int x = 10;
}
```

If you run it, you'll see the initalizer and the write, and if you filled in a file backing (maybe json using the keys and values, or some other serializer to handle more types), it should be able to save. You could also have the dtor save to a global buffer, then have a module destructor actually save it to a file (and the module constructor load the file too), so it doesn't try to read/write files on every function call.

All the variables will act as if they are static, since you can see the key here is the file and line number of the declaration, with no environmental input. But hey, it is fairly simple and should work.